# How to add 'Company Name' in customer register and billing info

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, onepage-checkout

I've been trying to add 'company name' on customer register and onepage checkout but unsuccessfully so far. I tried [Add Company Name to Billing/Shipping Dropdown in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/add-company-name-to-billing-shipping-dropdown-in-magento)  but it didn't help at all.

I can't believe there isn't a simple way of doing that.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check system configuration in the admin panel and find the module on the left-hand side for configuration

Comment: Can you be more specific where to look at? Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a specific module? Custom/third party?